# I am Trying to make a Button that shows red color when the value is true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am creating web apps using Pixabay API. I want a user to favorite an image and change the heart icon color to red. But it's not working.

I am using makeFav() method to add another boolean liked property to existing data.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data: {
      api: 'https://pixabay.com/api/?key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
      images: null, 
    },
    mounted() {
      this.getImages()
    },
    methods:{
    getImages: function(){
      if(localStorage.images){
        this.images = JSON.parse(localStorage.images)
        console.log("Local Image")
      }
      else{
        axios.get(this.api)
        .then(response => (
          this.images = response.data.hits,
          localStorage.images = JSON.stringify(this.images),
          console.log("API Image")
          ))
        .catch(error => (console.log(error)))
      }
    },
    makeFav: function(i){
      this.images[i].liked = !this.images[i].liked
    },
    }
    
})
```

In the HTML am using Vuetify cards. and Checking the color property but it's not working.

```
<v-col md="3" sm="6" v-for="(image, i) in images" :key="image.id"> 
   <v-card> 
      <v-img :src="image.previewURL"> 
      </v-img> 
      <v-card-actions> 
      <v-spacer></v-spacer> 
      <v-btn icon  @click="makeFav(i)"> 
          <v-icon :color="image.liked ? 'red' : ''">mdi-heart</v-icon> 
          {{image.likes}} 
      </v-btn> 
      <v-btn icon @click="downloadWithAxios(image.largeImageURL)"> 
          <v-icon>mdi-download</v-icon> 
      </v-btn> 
     </v-card-actions> 
   </v-card> 
</v-col>
```

[image]

Comment: what is `images` object structure?

Comment: Check the liked field after clicking. Is it changing to true for that object?

Comment: @KareemDabbeet [link](https://ibb.co/qyvrs5Z)

Comment: Can you provide a simple online demo? It does not have to include the API, just add a random image to your array

Comment: @MajedBadawi https://jsfiddle.net/jahidanowar/eunxp6bL/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vuejs has a bad reactivity for arrays. See the official doc : https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Arrays

> Vue cannot detect the following changes to an array:
>
> - When you directly set an item with the index, e.g. `vm.items[indexOfItem] = newValue`
> - When you modify the length of the array, e.g. `vm.items.length = newLength`

I found 2 solutions to fix your problem :

First one - `Vue.set` : https://jsfiddle.net/dp6g3qjn/

```
makeFav: function(i){
  Vue.set(this.images, i, { ...this.images[i], liked: !this.images[i].liked })
}
```

Second one - [`key`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key): https://jsfiddle.net/2cz0qfye/

```html
<v-col md="3" sm="6" v-for="(image, i) in images" :key="key(image)">
```

```js
key ({ id, liked}) {
  return `${id}_${liked}`
}
```

Note : I prefer the first solution because the object is not render again.